# How to produce a flatfile (?) from a hierarchical csv

Tags: python, shell, csv, data-structures, text-files

I need to do some data processing on a csv whose structure is as follows:

[image]

I need to collapse all the data from the TEXT column for rows where the FIELD entry is null and make it look like this:

```
FIELD              TEXT

P0190001, RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE(8) Universe:Households White Family Households: Married-couple family: With related children

P0190002, RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE(8) Universe:Households White Family Households: Married-couple family: No related children
```

... and so on.(The number of blank entries before the first valid entry in FIELD isn't always two, maybe be more or less)

Is there a simple efficient way to do this for a large (60,000 unique "fields") csv file? I'm looking for ways to do it on the command line rather than write a program.

Comment: Does the LH column change with each new category?

Comment: LH column does change but is quite irrelevant. I don't need it.

Comment: If you have 60,000 of these, the LH allows you to index the categories. Can you post a larger sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a command line solution, but a fun script.

```
import csv

csv_reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'))

# Read first two rows of field text out as a prefix.                            
prefix = ' '.join(csv_reader.next()[2].strip() for i in range(2))

def collapsed_row_iter():
    depth_value_list = []
    for (_, field_id, field_text, _) in csv_reader:
        # Count number of leading <SPACE> chars to determine depth.             
        pre_strip_text_len = len(field_text)
        field_text = field_text.lstrip()
        depth = pre_strip_text_len - len(field_text)

        depth_value_list_len = len(depth_value_list)
        if depth == depth_value_list_len + 1:
            # Append a new depth value.                                            
            depth_value_list.append(field_text.rstrip())

        if depth <= depth_value_list_len:
            # Truncate list to depth, append new value.                         
            del depth_value_list[depth:]
            depth_value_list.append(field_text.rstrip())

        else:
            # Depth value is greater than current_depth + 1                     
            raise ValueError

        # Only yield the row if field_id value is non-NULL.                     
        if field_id:
            yield (field_id, '%s %s' % (prefix, ' '.join(depth_value_list)))

# Get CSV writer object, write the header.                                      
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('collapsed.csv', 'wb'))
csv_writer.writerow(['FIELD', 'TEXT'])

# Iterate over collapsed rows, writing each to the output CSV.                  
for (field_id, collapsed_text) in collapsed_row_iter():
    csv_writer.writerow([field_id, collapsed_text])
```

Output:

```
FIELD,TEXT
P0190001,RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE (8) Universe: Households White Family Households: Married-couple family: With related children
P0190002,RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE (8) Universe: Households White Family Households: Married-couple family: No related children
P0190003,"RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE (8) Universe: Households White Family Households: Other family: Male householder, no wife present: With related children"
P0190004,"RACE OF HOUSEHOLDER BY HOUSEHOLD TYPE (8) Universe: Households White Family Households: Other family: Male householder, no wife present: No related children"
```

Comment: Hi derek, This script looks good, but I'm having trouble compiling it.
The message I get is:
``
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\collapse.py", line 40, in <module>
    for (field_id, collapsed_text) in collapsed_row_iter():
  File "C:\collapse.py", line 28, in collapsed_row_iter
    raise ValueError
ValueError
`


Where is field_id getting it's values from? I don't see it being initialized. I'm sorry but I don't know any python.

Comment: This error is explicitly being raised inside the `else` clause on line 28 by the statement `raise ValueError`, which is executed when the code encounters a depth level that is >1 levels deeper than the current level. I added this clause because I wasn't sure how you'd want to handle this situation. `field_id` is being assigned by the statement `for (_, field_id, field_text, _) in csv_reader:`. `csv_reader` is an iterator that returns a list of column values for each row in the file. Note that this statement expects exactly 4 column values and assigns 1 & 4 to throwaway variables named "_".

Comment: Oh I managed to fix it eventually. The first two rows are actually not a prefix, but part of the whole hierarchy; but I accounted for that and also changed the logic for detecting a new level just a bit. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!